# How To Require Lua Socket?

Tags: lua, luasocket

I'm very new to lua development with file manipulation, and now trying to import the lua socket package into my project according to [this post](http://giderosmobile.com/forum/discussion/1083/any-demo-code-for-lua-socket/p1), but I can't run even the code below.

I guess the error message indicates I need to import not only the socket.lua but also .\socket\core (probably .dll, since it doesn't have core.lua), while a reply at the post suggested importing only the file.

I'm stuck in just the beginning... What do I have to do for the next step?

```
local function main()
  local socket = require("socket")
end
main()

Exception in thread "main" com.naef.jnlua.LuaRuntimeException: ...n32.win32.x86_64\workspace\TestForCiv\src\socket.lua:13: module 'socket.core' not found:
    no field package.preload['socket.core']
    no file '.\socket\core.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\lua\socket\core.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\lua\socket\core\init.lua'
    ...(a bunch of no file errors continues)
```

Edit: I added the folder structure. Even I add the .dll file it returns the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the details of you configuration, but try this

```
require ("src.socket")
```

you should require a module from the root path of the lib

Comment: I successfully made it loads the files, thanks and sorry for the delay in the reply.